# Unit conversion application

Tags: c#, beginner, winforms, unit-conversion

I have a form with listboxes used for unit conversions. I'm using the [UnitsNet](https://github.com/anjdreas/UnitsNet) package.

Here are my questions:

1. Is this the proper approach?
2. If any changes must be made to this code, what are they?

[image]

```
private void listBoxControl1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UnitTypes enumValue = (UnitTypes)Enum.Parse(typeof(UnitTypes), listBoxControl1.SelectedItem.ToString());
    listBoxControl2.Items.Clear();
    listBoxControl3.Items.Clear();

    switch (enumValue)
    {
        case UnitTypes.Energy:
            listBoxControl2.Items.AddRange(typeof(EnergyUnits).GetEnumValues().Cast<object>().ToArray());
            listBoxControl3.Items.AddRange(typeof(EnergyUnits).GetEnumValues().Cast<object>().ToArray());
            break;
        case UnitTypes.Flow:
            listBoxControl2.Items.AddRange(typeof(FlowUnits).GetEnumValues().Cast<object>().ToArray());
            listBoxControl3.Items.AddRange(typeof(FlowUnits).GetEnumValues().Cast<object>().ToArray());
            break;
        case UnitTypes.Force:
            listBoxControl2.Items.AddRange(typeof(ForceUnits).GetEnumValues().Cast<object>().ToArray());
            listBoxControl3.Items.AddRange(typeof(ForceUnits).GetEnumValues().Cast<object>().ToArray());
            break;
        case UnitTypes.Frequency:
            listBoxControl2.Items.AddRange(typeof(FrequencyUnits).GetEnumValues().Cast<object>().ToArray());
            listBoxControl3.Items.AddRange(typeof(FrequencyUnits).GetEnumValues().Cast<object>().ToArray());
            break;
        case UnitTypes.Length:
            listBoxControl2.Items.AddRange(typeof(LengthUnits).GetEnumValues().Cast<object>().ToArray());
            listBoxControl3.Items.AddRange(typeof(LengthUnits).GetEnumValues().Cast<object>().ToArray());
            break;
        case UnitTypes.Number:
            listBoxControl2.Items.AddRange(typeof(NumberUnits).GetEnumValues().Cast<object>().ToArray());
            listBoxControl3.Items.AddRange(typeof(NumberUnits).GetEnumValues().Cast<object>().ToArray());
            break;
        case UnitTypes.Power:
            listBoxControl2.Items.AddRange(typeof(PowerUnits).GetEnumValues().Cast<object>().ToArray());
            listBoxControl3.Items.AddRange(typeof(PowerUnits).GetEnumValues().Cast<object>().ToArray());
            break;
        case UnitTypes.Pressure:
            listBoxControl2.Items.AddRange(typeof(PressureUnits).GetEnumValues().Cast<object>().ToArray());
            listBoxControl3.Items.AddRange(typeof(PressureUnits).GetEnumValues().Cast<object>().ToArray());
            break;
        case UnitTypes.Speed:
            listBoxControl2.Items.AddRange(typeof(SpeedUnits).GetEnumValues().Cast<object>().ToArray());
            listBoxControl3.Items.AddRange(typeof(SpeedUnits).GetEnumValues().Cast<object>().ToArray());
            break;
        case UnitTypes.Temperature:
            listBoxControl2.Items.AddRange(typeof(TemperatureUnits).GetEnumValues().Cast<object>().ToArray());
            listBoxControl3.Items.AddRange(typeof(TemperatureUnits).GetEnumValues().Cast<object>().ToArray());
            break;
        case UnitTypes.Time:
            listBoxControl2.Items.AddRange(typeof(TimeUnits).GetEnumValues().Cast<object>().ToArray());
            listBoxControl3.Items.AddRange(typeof(TimeUnits).GetEnumValues().Cast<object>().ToArray());
            break;
        case UnitTypes.Timing:
            listBoxControl2.Items.AddRange(typeof(TimingUnits).GetEnumValues().Cast<object>().ToArray());
            listBoxControl3.Items.AddRange(typeof(TimingUnits).GetEnumValues().Cast<object>().ToArray());
            break;
        case UnitTypes.Torque:
            listBoxControl2.Items.AddRange(typeof(TorqueUnits).GetEnumValues().Cast<object>().ToArray());
            listBoxControl3.Items.AddRange(typeof(TorqueUnits).GetEnumValues().Cast<object>().ToArray());
            break;
        case UnitTypes.Volume:
            listBoxControl2.Items.AddRange(typeof(VolumeUnits).GetEnumValues().Cast<object>().ToArray());
            listBoxControl3.Items.AddRange(typeof(VolumeUnits).GetEnumValues().Cast<object>().ToArray());
            break;
    }
}

//This is hit when selection changes in listboxes or when value changes in 'Input Value' textbox
//This handles only Length unit as of now.
private void updateValues(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UnitTypes unitType = (UnitTypes)Enum.Parse(typeof(UnitTypes), listBoxControl1.SelectedItem.ToString());

    switch (unitType)
    {
        case UnitTypes.Energy:
            convertEnrgyUnit();
            break;
        case UnitTypes.Flow:
            ConvertFlowUnit();
            break;
        case UnitTypes.Force:
            ConvertForceUnit();
            break;
        case UnitTypes.Frequency:
            ConvertFrequencyUnit();
            break;
        case UnitTypes.Length:
            convertLengthUnit();
            break;
        case UnitTypes.Number:

            break;
        case UnitTypes.Power:

            break;
        case UnitTypes.Pressure:

            break;
        case UnitTypes.Speed:

            break;
        case UnitTypes.Temperature:

            break;
        case UnitTypes.Time:

            break;
        case UnitTypes.Timing:

            break;
        case UnitTypes.Torque:

            break;
        case UnitTypes.Volume:

            break;
    }
}


private void convertLengthUnit()
{
    LengthUnits energyInputVal = LengthUnits.Feet;
    LengthUnits energyOutputVal = LengthUnits.Feet;
    if (listBoxControl2.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        energyInputVal = (LengthUnits)listBoxControl2.SelectedItem;
    }
    if (listBoxControl3.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        energyOutputVal = (LengthUnits)listBoxControl3.SelectedItem;
    }

    if (listBoxControl2.SelectedItem != null && listBoxControl3.SelectedItem != null && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textEdit1.Text))
    {
        Length inputVal = Length.FromFeet(1);
        decimal outputVal = 0;
        switch (energyInputVal)
        {
            case LengthUnits.Feet:
                inputVal = Length.FromFeet(Convert.ToDouble(textEdit1.Text));
                break;
            case LengthUnits.Inches:
                inputVal = Length.FromInches(Convert.ToDouble(textEdit1.Text));
                break;
            case LengthUnits.Kilometers:
                inputVal = Length.FromKilometers(Convert.ToDouble(textEdit1.Text));
                break;
            case LengthUnits.Meters:
                inputVal = Length.FromMeters(Convert.ToDouble(textEdit1.Text));
                break;
            case LengthUnits.Miles:
                inputVal = Length.FromMiles(Convert.ToDouble(textEdit1.Text));
                break;
        }

        switch (energyOutputVal)
        {
            case LengthUnits.Feet:
                outputVal = Convert.ToDecimal(inputVal.Feet);
                break;
            case LengthUnits.Inches:
                outputVal = Convert.ToDecimal(inputVal.Inches);
                break;
            case LengthUnits.Kilometers:
                outputVal = Convert.ToDecimal(inputVal.Kilometers);
                break;
            case LengthUnits.Meters:
                outputVal = Convert.ToDecimal(inputVal.Meters);
                break;
            case LengthUnits.Miles:
                outputVal = Convert.ToDecimal(inputVal.Miles);
                break;
        }

        textEdit2.Text = outputVal.ToString();
    }
}


private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listBoxControl1.Items.AddRange(typeof(UnitTypes).GetEnumValues().Cast<object>().ToArray());
}
```

Comment: _"Instead of manually doing some calculations in code i'm looking for some library or open source that does all these calculations for us."_ Would somethinhg like [this](https://www.codeproject.com/kb/library/measurement_conversion.aspx) work for you?

Comment: Definitely, all I want is a form that can make all conversions and i'm just a beginner, after looking at my code I thought there might definitely be a better way of writing this logic.

Comment: Why not use google? It can covert everything :P

Comment: Well, the stuff I've been linking to is configurable via XML. All you need is to populate your  ListBox controls from the defined consverters.

Comment: @t3chb0t I will ask my manager and see if he could do so :P

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Sorry but as a beginner in c# or coding I have no idea what you are talking about.

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/UnitsNet/   .....I see this link might be helpful but i'm not sure how I could use this

Comment: So you are not really looking for a review, right?

Comment: @t3chb0t No,  i'm looking for  review and my solution here does not actually do unit conversion. Looking for unit conversion solution as well.

Comment: Why is no one responding to my question? Is something wrong in my question ?

Comment: I guess the third quesiton is discouraging people from reviewing your code becasue it suggests that you are not really interested in improving it but rather in implementing a 3rd party library.

Comment: @t3chb0t What's wrong in doing so? I have so many unit conversions in my code. If I don't use any library for these conversions I have manually write code to do all the calculations which is a big pain and makes my code really huge.

Comment: Then you need to ask that question at [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com). What's the purpose of reviewing your code if you want to use a library anyway?

Comment: Implement the unit converstion with a lib of your choice and let that code be reviewed.

Comment: I updated my code using  https://github.com/anjdreas/UnitsNet  package. Can someone please review my code now?

Answer (score 1):

First, split your methods up into smaller units. For example, `convertLengthUnit` should have this general structure (and PascalCase naming):

```
private void ConvertLengthUnit()
{
    var lengthInputVal = LengthUnits.Feet;
    var lengthOutputVal = LengthUnits.Feet;

    if (listBoxControl2.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        lengthInputVal = (LengthUnits)listBoxControl2.SelectedItem;
    }

    if (listBoxControl3.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        lengthOutputVal = (LengthUnits)listBoxControl3.SelectedItem;
    }

    if (listBoxControl2.SelectedItem != null && listBoxControl3.SelectedItem != null && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textEdit1.Text))
    {
        textEdit2.Text = Convert(lengthInputVal, lengthOutputVal);
    }
}
```

Note that I extracted the actually conversion to another method. Also, please give your controls better names. Perhaps `inputTypes` instead of `listBoxControl2`. You can change these names in the Properties window.

Those `switch` blocks are a pain to read, and probably even more of a pain to update. Unfortunately, I don't see a better alternative at the moment, other than to extract them into, for example:

```
Length GetInput()
{
    switch (energyInputVal)
    {
        case LengthUnits.Feet:
            return Length.FromFeet(Convert.ToDouble(textEdit1.Text));
        case LengthUnits.Inches:
            return Length.FromInches(Convert.ToDouble(textEdit1.Text));
        // others...
    }
}
```

And:

```
GetOutput(LengthUnits outputType, Length data)
{
    switch (energyOutputVal)
    {
        case LengthUnits.Feet:
            return Convert.ToDecimal(inputVal.Feet);
        case LengthUnits.Inches:
            return Convert.ToDecimal(inputVal.Inches);
        // ...
    }
}
```

Now, you have a method with one responsibility, and it will probably be a little easier to make sure you update everything if you add any new types.

I would use these same principles to load the input/output types. I would create a method like so:

```
void AddUnits<T>()
{
    var units = typeof(T).GetEnumValues().Cast<object>().ToArray();
    listBoxControl2.Items.AddRange(units);
    listBoxControl3.Items.AddRange(units);
}
```

Then call it like:

```
switch (enumValue)
{
    case UnitTypes.Energy:
        AddUnits<EnergyUnits>();
    case UnitTypes.Flow:
        AddUnits<FlowUnits>();
        break;
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@hosch250 's [answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/163223/32101) covers a lot of good feedback, so I will focus on how you can further simplify the switch statements.

In your comments you mentioned switching to [Units.NET](https://github.com/anjdreas/UnitsNet/), which allows you to do something like this:

```
double inputValue = 5; // Obtain from input text box
var inputUnit = LengthUnit.Meter; // Obtain from list selection
var outputUnit = LengthUnit.Centimeter; // Obtain from list selection

double outputValue = Length.From(inputValue, inputUnit).As(outputUnit); // 500
```

This covers the case when `Length` is selected.

You already have code in place to `switch` to a different conversion code for when `Length`, `Mass` etc is selected and you still need something like that to handle those separately, but Units.NET helps convert between units and providing an enum like `LengthUnit` for enumerating all possible units to convert between.

Now, I was inspired by this scenario and it's been on my mind for some time, so I went ahead and added support for dynamic unit conversion and it's now available in [UnitsNet 3.70.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/UnitsNet/3.70.0).

The example now becomes:

```
// Get quantities for populating quantity UI selector
QuantityType[] quantityTypes = Enum.GetValues(typeof(QuantityType)).Cast<QuantityType>().ToArray();

// If Length is selected, get length units for populating from/to UI selectors
LengthUnit[] lengthUnits = Length.Units;

// Perform conversion by using .ToString() on selected quantity and units
double centimeters = UnitSystem.ConvertByName(5, "Length", "Meter", "Centimeter");
```

I also added an alternative method `ConvertByAbbreviation()`, that take unit abbreviations "m" and "cm" instead.